# Why does RegExp.rightContext raise an invalid access error inside an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, regex

This function raises an "invalid access" error in Chrome, returns the wrong result in IE (pirate_bar_pirate_baz), and works as expected in Firefox (pirate_bar_ninja_baz). If you remove the global flag from the regular expression, it works fine, but only for the first "foo" instead of both. What's the problem?

```
regex = /foo/g;
//regex = /foo/;

"foo_bar_foo_baz".replace(regex, function(str) {
  if (RegExp.rightContext == "_baz") {
    return "ninja";
  } else {
    return "pirate"; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems like a bug. `"xx".replace(/x/g,function(){RegExp.rightContext;});` also throws `"illegal access"` in Chrome, while just fetching the property shouldn't do this I assume.

Comment: The property is deprecated, should thus not be used anymore and probably won't receive fixes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_Features Use a different expression to include the string in the match that you need for your `if`.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, many older RegExp properties are deprecated.
Using another syntax is safer (and often shorter)

```
var regex=  /foo(?=_bar)?/g;
"foo_bar_foo_baz".replace(regex, function(a, b){
    return b? "ninja":"pirate";
});
```

returned value: (String) **pirate_bar_ninja_baz**

Comment: This doesn't quite work. "robots_foo_bar_foo_baz_foo_bar" returns "robots_ninja_bar_ninja_baz_ninja_bar". Expected output is "robots_ninja_bar_pirate_baz_ninja_bar".